# How to edit multiple locations in the console at the same time

Tags: c++, console, cursor

Is there any way to edit two (or more) locations in the console at the same time? Essentially, I have a bunch of objects that are moving all over the screen and the program gets bogged down because the cursor has to move all over the place to update their locations every frame. Thanks for the help!